# Как определить количество устройств связанных интерфейсом RS485

Tags: arduino, modbus

есть одно master устройство на ардуине , и N-ое количество slave устройств с уникальными адресами которые мастер не знает , как можно сообщить мастеру сколько устройств подключено если говорить может только одно ? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

В протоколах, использующих RS485, передача любой порции данных обычно инициируется мастером. Запрос, выполняемый мастером, должен содержать адрес устройства-получателя. И только устройство-получатель, обладающее таким адресом, должно на такой запрос откликаться.

Таким образом, присутствие на шине устройства можно выяснить путём инициализационного (или же периодического) опроса мастером каждого из доступных в диапазоне адресов. Если ему удастся получить ответ до истечения таймаута, это будет означать, что устройство с таким адресом на шине присутствует, и можно запускать процесс чтения данных.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поразмышлять на эту тему, да.

Пусть мастер при первом обращении слейва генерирует и отправляет слейву уникальный id, который слейв будет отправлять мастеру при последующих обращениях. А при первом обращении к мастеру слейв пусть присылает 0. Мастер должен хранить массив структур {идентификатор_слейва, таймстамп}. Так же следует гарантировать обязательный "ping" от слейва мастеру за определенный промежуток времени, если не было других обращений. При получении пинга или другого сообщения - у соответствующего идентификатора обновляется таймстамп. Если нет - соответвующий идентификатор должен быть удалён из массива. Таким образом можно будет сказать, что на таком то промежутке времени с мастером контактировало столько то устройств.

Comment: Но как я смогу задать последовательность обращения слейвов к мастеру , чтобы они не начинали все вместе передавать в канал одновременно ?

Comment: Значит инициализировать общение должен мастер. Ну, то есть алгоритм немного разворачивается. Не слейв в мастер ходит, а мастер пытается к слейвам ходить. Впрочем это не снимает возможности прихода слейва в мастер одновременно с кем-то. Надо подумать...

Comment: Я думаю что в мастере по-любому должен быть заложен диапазон адресов слейвов , по которым нужно проходить при инициализации , а потом их и опрашивать

Comment: Так, судя по библиотеке https://github.com/Protoneer/RS485-Arduino-Library (которая по большому счету является обёрткой над SoftwareSerial) , приходить в мастер должы всётаки слейвы. К тому же я не увидел какой либо возможности определить занята ли линия или нет. Потом немного поискал... В общем, вам нужен мультиплексер, чтототипа вот такого: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/8970